# c++ overloaded parentheses operator slower than direct access to array member

Tags: c++, performance, matrix, optimization, matrix-multiplication

At the moment I am trying to figure out why my naive matrix-matrix-multiplication is slower (0.7 sec) when I use the overloaded parentheses operator (`//first multiplication`). If I don't use them (`//second multiplication`) and the multiplication directly access the class member array `data_` it is about twice as fast (0.35 sec). I use my own matrix class as defined in `Matrix.h`.

Why is there such a significant difference in speed? Is there something wrong with my copy constructor? Is there so much "overhead" in calling the overloaded operator function that it justifies for that kind of performance penalty?

There is one more question / weird behavior: When you exchange the two inner most loops (`x` and `inner`) with each other, then the multiplication gets (of course) really slow, but both multiplications take almost the SAME time (7 sec) now. Why does it take the same time for them in this case, but before there was a ~50% performance difference.

edit: The program is compiled the following way: `g++ -c -std=c++0x -O3 -DNDEBUG`

Thank you so much for your help!

My main function looks like this:

```
#include "Matrix.h"
int main(){
    Matrix m1(1024,1024, 2.0);
    Matrix m2(1024,1024, 2.5);
    Matrix m3(1024,1024);

    //first multiplication
    for(int y = 0; y < 1024; ++y){
        for(int inner = 0; inner < 1024; ++inner){
            for(int x = 0; x < 1024; ++x){
                m3(y,x) += m1(y, inner) * m2(inner, x);
            }
        }
    }

    //second multiplication
    for(int y = 0; y < 1024; ++y){
        for(int inner = 0; inner < 1024; ++inner){
            for(int x = 0; x < 1024; ++x){
                m3.data_[y*1024+x] += m1.data_[y*1024+inner]*m2.data_[inner*1024+inner];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the part of `Matrix.h`:

```
class Matrix{

public:
    Matrix();
    Matrix(int sizeY, int sizeX);
    Matrix(int sizeY, int sizeX, double init);
    Matrix(const Matrix & orig);
    ~Matrix(){delete[] data_;}
    double & operator() (int y, int x);
    double operator() (int y, int x) const;

    double * data_;

private:    
    int sizeX_;
    int sizeY_;

}
```

And here the Implementation of `Matrix.h`

```
Matrix::Matrix()
    : sizeX_(0),
    sizeY_(0),
    data_(nullptr)
{ }

Matrix::Matrix(int sizeY, int sizeX)
    : sizeX_(sizeX),
    sizeY_(sizeY),
    data_(new double[sizeX*sizeY]())
{
    assert( sizeX > 0 );
    assert( sizeY > 0 );
}

Matrix::Matrix(int sizeY, int sizeX, double init)
    : sizeX_(sizeX), 
    sizeY_(sizeY)
{   
    assert( sizeX > 0 );
    assert( sizeY > 0 );
    data_ = new double[sizeX*sizeY];
    std::fill(data_, data_+(sizeX_*sizeY_), init);
}

Matrix::Matrix(const Matrix & orig)
    : sizeX_(orig.sizeX_),
    sizeY_(orig.sizeY_)
{
    data_ = new double[orig.sizeY_*orig.sizeX_];
    std::copy(orig.data_, orig.data_+(sizeX_*sizeY_), data_);
}


double & Matrix::operator() (int y, int x){
    assert( x >= 0 && x < sizeX_);
    assert( y >= 0 && y < sizeY_);
    return data_[y*sizeX_ + x];
}

double Matrix::operator() (int y, int x) const {
    assert( x >= 0 && x < sizeX_);
    assert( y >= 0 && y < sizeY_);
    return data_[y*sizeX_ + x];
}
```

**EDIT2:** Turns out I used the wrong array access for the `//second multiplication`. I changed it to `m3.data_[y*1024+x] += m1.data_[y*1024+inner]*m2.data_[inner*1024+x];` and now both multiplications take the same time.
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: The access functions are basically one `return` statement (`assert` is removed in non-debug builds) so try putting the function inline in the class definition and see if it makes a difference. Then build with optimizations enabled.

Comment: how did you measure? optimizations turned on?

Comment: What happens if you run the second case first and the first case second?

Comment: @tobi303  I used the flag -O3 and measured the time with a function provided by my university.

Comment: Switching the order of the loops changes the cache access pattern.  If properly optimized, I would think that "inner" as the inner loop would be the fastest.  With "x" as inner, the intermediate result can no longer be held in a register, but actually has to be read and then rewritten to memory.  Cache optimization for matrix multiplies is a thing.  Google will find you plenty of material to read.

Comment: @NathanOliver the behavior stays the same.

Comment: Have you fixed the location of the accessor functions yet, as @Someprogrammerdude mentions?  They *must* go in the header file so the optimizer can get rid of the function call.

Comment: @Peter but why is there a difference between the two cache-optimized version (0.7 sec vs. 0.35 sec) but NO difference between the two not-cache-optimized versions (both about 7 sec)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude @Peter I just added `inline` to the two overloaded parentheses operator functions and their implementations. But the results are still the same.

Comment: Adding "inline" isn't enough.  The function definitions need to be in the header file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your two versions are not computing the same thing:

In the first you have:

m3(y,x) += m1(y, inner) * m2(inner, **x**);

But in the second you have

m3.data_[y*1024+x] += m1.data_[y*1024+inner]*m2.data_[inner*1024+**inner**];

The second one can factor inner out and instead do inner * (1024 + 1) which can be optimized a number of ways that the first can't.

What are the outputs of the two versions? Do they match?

Edit: Another answerer is quite right suggesting that the dimensions in the class not being constant will take some optimizations off the table; in the first version the compiler doesn't know that the size is a power of two so it uses general-purpose multiplication but in the second version it knows that one of the operands is 1024 (not just a constant but a **compile time** constant) so it can use fast multiplication (left shift by the power of two).

(Apologies for my earlier answer about NDEBUG: I had the page open for a while so didn't see your edit with the compilation line.)

Comment: Yes you are correct. My bad. I totally oversaw the wrong access in the `data_` member. I changed it to `m3.data_[y*1024+x] += m1.data_[y*1024+inner]*m2.data_[inner*1024+x];` and now both versions are calculated in the same time. Thank you very much for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the difference is that in the operator() version, sizeX_ is not const, and this may be preventing the compiler from optimizing something, i.e. loading sizeX_ into a register repeatedly.  Try declaring sizeX_ and sizeY_ const in the class definition.

That and you should inline the functions in the header, as has been suggested in the comments.